# How to disable loading of unreachable resources in web pages?

Tags: javascript

Most google server IPs are blocked in my country, so if we want to access these IPs we would have to use VPN. This seems to include sites such as ajax.googleapis.com. The problem is there are a lot of web sites are using ajax.googleapis.com as a place to load some javascript libraries. However, these sites themselves are not blocked. So, in the case where VPN is not available, and I want to be able to access these sites, I have to wait for quite a long time before it timeout in loading such unreachable resources (at least it seems to be this reason). Also I think some Google statistics sites references in the pages are also subject to such issue.

For example, the following is taken from this link https://www.lens.org/lens/:

```js
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/lens/js/head/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

My question is, how to disable loading such unreachable resources? I was thinking of a browser extension to have some "blacklist" of such links, and replace it with some alternatives, or just disable loading them if no alternatives are available, so that it can load faster? I think I will sacrifice some functionality due to that, but I can still access some content quicker (better than waiting).

I confirmed the issue with Chrome Developer Tools in network tab: [image: Chrome network tab for loading page https://www.lens.org/lens/]

Comment: Why not just host these files on your own site?

Comment: @jeff Maybe your solution is the same as Darren H answer below. This is a possible solution, but I'll have to maintain a website or something myself. My 1st impression is that some extension can be used to either disable it, or set alternative URL when I found such links in the 1st place, then it records into a database.

Comment: By doing further search, I found [Requestly](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) which solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many potential solutions to this, but here is one that is probably the easiest to implement and understand for someone who doesn't want to go coding their own browser extension or start running third party software.

### Modify your hosts file

Simply add the following line to your hosts file

```
 mywebsite.com ajax.googleapis.com
```

You can find your hosts file easily

On *nix systems (mac / linux) it will usually be found at `/etc/hosts`

On windows systems it will usually be found at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

You can find a full list of where to find it on other operating systems at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Now whenever your browser (or any other software) is instructed to retrieve anything from ajax.googleapis.com it will instead look on mywebsite.com (use your own server for this, or even localhost!)

Now just put all of the common libraries, such as jQuery, onto mywebsite.com and it will load the libraries from there. Any websites that include these libraries will simply work as if they could access Google

Comment: Thanks, a possible solution. but see my reply to jeff.

Comment: If you find a site that maintains an up-to-date copy of all of the common libraries, then you could just set that site in your hosts file. Be sure it is a site you trust though! If you use some other external site to supply jQuery file for you and that site gets hacked, the hackers could put malicious code in the jQuery file which could cause all sorts of problems for you. Maybe host yourself and have your server pull once per week from Google automatically so you always have latest code available. I'm sure there will be a full list of files somewhere

Comment: I think https://cdnjs.com/ is such a server. But there is a problem with the "host" mapping solution, I need to map the exact path of a library from ajax.googleapis.com path to the cdnjs.com path. So I think an browser extension is more feasible. Then my question remains how to handle this replacement with javascript. OK, maybe I'll have to did into writing an extension? Maybe such extension already exists?